# How to install and use CakePHP plugins in Croogo?

Tags: cakephp, croogo

I want to use some CakePHP plugins such as [CakeGrid](https://github.com/Mehrdad-Dadkhah/CakeGrid) in Croogo 2.
How can i do it?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:
Open file Config/bootstrap.php and Add code end of file

```
CakePlugin::load('CakeGrid');
```

Then add changes according to [instruction in croogo controller and view file](https://github.com/Mehrdad-Dadkhah/CakeGrid/blob/master/README.md).